# Preventing Map Position Changes When Adding Annotations

Tags: javascript, mapkit-js

I am using Apple MapKit JS to display places on a map. My application fetches places within the polygon of the currently visible area when the user pans the map. However, when I remove old annotations and add new ones, the MapKit library automatically adjusts the position of the map view, causing an undesired effect for users.

Issue:

When adding new annotations, the map changes its position, disrupting the user experience.
Expected Behavior:

I want the map to stay exactly as it is, without any changes in position, when annotations are changed.

Note: The annotations are properly being displayed.

```
 const updateMap = (places) => {
    const annotations = buildAnnotations(places);
    map.removeAnnotations(map?.annotations);
    map.addAnnotations(annotations);
}
```

IMO there should be a straightforward solution to this but I don't find any helpful methods in the docs to prevent this behaviour.

I scouted through the documentation and Stackoverflow, and in desperate attempts I asked Github Copilot to help...

Everything I tried resulted in the same effect that the Map is behaving in an undesired way, UX-wise. The map should keep the mapRegion when changing the annotations so there is no jumping for the user.